# I have developed and application with Mern. I wanna know should I change my react js api calls to localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually I have created applicaiton with `MERN` (MongoDB, Express js, React js, Node js) and want to build and deploy it. All my API calls are from localhost, I wanna know how should I do that in this case. Should I change the api calls to another  link?

Comment: You need to use env in development set `api_server` env to local express js server. When you deploy it change env in deployment server to hosted api server

Comment: ok let me try it.

Comment: deploy your backend i.e, express project first then replace the URL with the localhost in your frontend application.

Comment: if you use create-react-app create `.env.production` and set the hosted server url. Create `.env.local` and set the local server url.

Answer (score 0):

right, you have to change it. The API url must be replaced with the API url that you have hosted later.

Comment: and in this case, after deployment, can I change that? In other words, I should deploy first time, then change the API url and after that change it with domain name ?

Comment: Yes, and try to re-deploy it again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your express server APIs from elsewhere, you first need to deploy the express project on a server. Once hosted, you need to use the public address of that server and replace it with `localhost`.

Say your server's public address is `103.102.16.21` and your API is currently accessible at `localhost:8000/api/x-api`, after deploying your express project on this server, you can access it at `103.102.16.21:8000/api/x-api`, if you have set the default port to 8000.

A guide for reference: https://codedamn.com/news/web-development/deploy-mern-stack-application